# Are there mathematical objects (like matrices) which behave like shorthand operators for complicated calculations?

Tags: functions

Matrix multiplication involves summing a product. It is appropriate where you need to multiply things together and then add.

Are there more examples like this ? Namely, to use a mathematical object, function to compute a function in an alternative way ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Misakov I think this question is asking: "Matrix multiplication is a kind of shorthand for performing a certain kind of multiplication-followed-by-addition operation.  Are there other mathematical objects (like matrices) which behave like shorthand operators for some other familiar, possibly complicated, calculation (like multiplication-then-addition)?"

Comment: Thank you @user326210. I borrowed you title, if you don't mind.

Comment: Yes it is possible to design matrices to do many complicated calculations in a systematic way. In the matrix representation theory of groups matrix multiplication over a simpler field ( class or set of numbers ) can "represent" multiplication of scalars of more complicated types of "numbers". And higher dimensional linear objects can approximate non-linear things on smaller spaces. For example you can do calculations with complex numbers as addition and multiplications of 2x2 real valued matrices.

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternate ways to define matrix multiplication - i.e. as the composition of linear transformations. The fact that this results in summing a product then comes from the underlying structure of linear transforms.

The composition of non-linear transformations would similarly require using a mathematical object (namely a non-linear transform) to compute the resulting composition transformation.